# symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I uploaded my symfony2 project to server grove. The main page loads, but all the links are broken. I tried adding app.php to the web address. It did work, but:

I have routes like this one:

www.something.com/app.php/something

I want them to be:

www.something.com/something.

I've been reading, and I should put some rewrite rules on the .htaccess.

I found these rules, but they don't seem to work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Francisco Ochoa, look at the log file. app/logs/ where you can find the error.

Comment: is mod_rewrite actually enabled?

Comment: thanks Inori. It's a nice tip ;). I checked it and yes, it's enabled.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html. If this is not solving your problem please open a new question.

Comment: I agree. I can't think of any change in Symfony since 2012 that would need to any change to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file (inside the web directory):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I added it but when I went to www.something.com, it says that there was an error...

Comment: did you remove everything else in the file?

Comment: If anyone else gets the 400 bad request sent error from apache
try adding a slash to the rewrite i.e.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]

Comment: this suggestions just costed me alot of time, getting an error, Options not allowed here

Comment: When I deploy to production (commenting RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L] and uncommenting RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]) it gives me an error. If I leave it like this solution, it works, but it redirects to app_dev.php :( Any help?

Answer (score 26):

To improve upon whistlergreg's answer, I added a line so that the bundles folder is not broken. This will make sure external resources such as images are not broken.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^/web/app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/web/app.php - [L]

    # Fix the bundles folder
    RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have enabled rewrite module. This code is executed if mod_rewrite.c is enabled. You must only enable mod_rewrite in apache2.
http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-enable-and-disable-apache-modules/

For example in Ubuntu:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, ... remember to uncomment (if commented) the apache configuration:

`LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so`

### MacOsX

`/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the full path to your assets(full url). I had the same issue when I deployed my first symfony application

My root directory (public_html folder in most of the case).htaccess file looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^projectName/ /projectName/web/app.php/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```