# Symfony2 disable app.php from direct access

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php)

I've been working with a `.htaccess` to remove the access to `app.php` from my **Symfony2** project. I want users to access the project from a url like this:

> **http://localhost:8888/Social-Shows/web/shows**

But i need to remove access from this url

> **http://localhost:8888/Social-Shows/web/app_dev.php/shows**

Right now my .htaccess let me access both address, here's my .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteOptions Inherit
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/shows
   RewriteRule ^(.*) web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

That may not be possible. You shouldn't really remove access from `app.php` because it is the entry point to your application. What you may do with `.htaccess`, instead, is rewrite the url to make it look as if there were no app.php. Which should already be accomplished by **Symfony2**'s default `.htaccess`.