# .htaccess redirect normal url to query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a url of the form:

```
www.example.com/r/abc/1234
```

that I want to rewrite to:

```
www.example.com/r.php?deb=abc&id=1234
```

And another url:

```
www.example.com/r/12bcd-qsqs-343-wdwd/1234
```

which should be rewritten to:

```
www.example.com/r.php?abc_id=12bcd-qsqs-343-wdwd&id=1234
```

Both of these rule should be handled by .htaccess. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pass all into a script of your own and than inside that PHP script process the URI as one parameter. That is much more less specific to the webserver you are running on and more flexible. This normally only needs a single or very few rules. Compare: [symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the URIs that you want to redirect look similar except that 2nd one has hyphens `-` in first query parameter.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^r/([^-]+)/(.+)/?$ r.php?deb=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^r/([a-z0-9-]+)/(.+)/?$ r.php?abc_id=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with little changes I have made it work, But now the problem is its working on my localhost but when I transferred it on the server were I am running virtualhost  Its not working can you help ?

Comment: On the server make sure .htaccess is enabled and then if .htaccess is correctly paced in DOCUMENT_ROOT directory. If everything is right then add `R` flag in above 2 RewriteRule lines to see what is the final URI on server.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Is there some how I can keep contact with you any social site or anything ?

Comment: You're welcome. Here is LinkedIn Contact: http://www.linkedin.com/in/anubhavasrivastava

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ path_to_php_files/$1.php?deb=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Unfortunately with this rule, you would have the first $_GET parameter always deb and I hope you have the DirectoryIndex set up corectly. I do not think that for

```
www.example.com/r/abc/1234
www.example.com/r/12bcd-qsqs-343-wdwd/1234
```

you can delivrer the abc and 12bcd-qsqs-343-wdwd to 2 different $_GET parameters if you have dynamic links.

Comment: Won't work because RewriteRule doesn't match starting slash `/`.

Comment: Actually if you notice OP wants to redirect in 2 different ways using 2 different query parameters.