# hide directory for symfony2 app in url

Tags: .htaccess, url, symfony, hide

The app.php is hidden from url like this:

RewriteEngine On

```
#<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
#    RewriteBase /
#</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

But before it, there is:  /symfony/web/

How to hide it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `DocumentRoot` in your Apache configuration to point to the `web/` directory.

Edit `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf` (your path may vary when using other distributions like Ubuntu):

```
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/webapp/symfony/web

    <Directory /path/to/your/webapp/symfony/web>
        ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: okay will try it in momemt but the .htaccess is working in /web at my localhost. But not working on different server. Any ideas why? And the error is: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /symfony/web/ on this server.

Comment: Check if the (*nix) file permissions are correctly set and owned by the same user/group where your webserver process is running as well as you don't exclude any users in your webserver config (`Order allow,deny` etc.)

Comment: I am not sure what u mean .. please i am noob in this stuff. But this is how ls looks like http://www.upnito.sk/0/tn7gmym434bn3qv3c6dyxz2ntbgvb2vq.png

Comment: mod_rewrite is _not_ the important thing here, it's the Apache config. If you're a noob start reading something about Apache vhost-configuration and about how to setup Symfony2 applications - the step you're trying to achieve is mentioned in the beginner's tutorial of Symfony2...