# symfony2 .htaccess hide app.php from url

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, url-rewriting

I am trying to hide the app.php from url

I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

Which works okay.. but when user visit

```
domain.com/app.php/Home/
```

than the url is still

```
domain.com/app.php/Home/
```

and i want have only

```
domain.com/Home
```

How to solve it?

I tried:

```
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/app.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)app.php/(.*)?$ /$2 [R=301,L]
```

Which work as i need but when i do some action dynamic jquery ajax action i get error 405.

Comment: you have uncommented ( removed the # ) the "#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/app.php" directive before you actually tried it , did you? :)

Comment: nice joke :) Yes i did :D As i said: Which work as i need ... but this do a 405 error problem while using ajax etc.

Comment: please try out my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled. You have to do on your machine:

- `sudo a2enmod rewrite` (or enable module in other way if you don't have `a2enmod`)
- `service apache2 restart` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Next, you have to set `AllowOverride All` in your vhost config to be sure URLs will be properly catched by Symfony's `web/.htaccess`.

---

Additional info: in Symfony's `web/.htaccess`:

`<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>`

If `mod_rewrite` is not enabled, apache uses `mod_alias` to pass all requests through `app.php`. So if you enter root URL of your domain and you're redirected to `app.php` it's probably because of `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something like this but i am not sure if its good solution?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/app.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)app.php/(.*)?$ /$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution to your problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hm.. i have read it but i am not sure how this can help me? Its not seems to work ... please check my answer what you say on it?