# web/app.php is not removing in symfony2

Tags: php, apache, symfony

i have created first Symfony application but the url is so large

http:// ip address/repair/web/app_dev.php/home

http:// ip address/repair/web/app.php/home

i want to make it as http:// ip address/repair/home

here is  httpd.conf of apache2

NameVirtualHost something  ip address

ServerName "repair"

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/repair/web"

<Directory "/var/www/repair/web">
   DirectoryIndex app.php
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/app\.php/(.*) /$1
</Directory>
```

my .htaccess of in web folder of symfony contains

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On  

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

i have reloded the mod-Rewrite of apache2 too

iam getting error

The requested URL /repair/home was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at ip address Port 80

Comment: possible duplicate of [symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php)

Comment: i followed the link and added the code in .htaccess but showing same error do i need to write any code in app_dev.php or app.php in order to redirect to home page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access site by ip you need to copy your code to "localhost" directory (/var/www, e.g.)

Comment: ya i have my symfony project under localhost var/www/repair and i will access it with http://10.70.70.77/repair/web/app_dev.php/home

Comment: Can you please help me 2Kai with this issue

Answer (score 0):

The `AllowOverride None` line in your Apache config is causing the .htaccess file to be ignored.

If you replace it with `AllowOverride All` Apache will follow the directives in your .htaccess file.

You can find more information about AllowOverride [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: i have did you said even it is showing The requested URL /repair/home was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at ip address Port 80

Comment: i have symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php 2 link of stack overfolw but even i get the error can you please help with the issue

Comment: @bhari Did you restart Apache after applying settings?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that you actually have mod-rewrite loaded for Apache.  On a Debian 6 install with Apache 2, the module was available, but it wasn't loaded.  In order to load it, you can add a symlink in the mods-enabled directory to the module in the mods-available directory like this:

```
root@server:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load ./rewrite.load
```

Then you'll need to restart Apache2 to get it to reload its configuration.  On Debian that would be `sudo service apache2 restart`