# A redirect Script that Carries out the Full URL path of the previous page

Tags: php, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I was wondering if this is even possible... I am working on this flow

A user is on "ask-now" (`http://domain.com/ask-now/`) page and click "ask" link, he will be redirected to "`redirect.php`" and "`redirect.php`" will redirect to `answer.php` but the URL of `answer.php` must carry the full url of `http://domain.com/ask-now/` Like this form `http://domain.com/answer.php/?ask=http://domain.com/ask-now/`

and everytime user click "ask" on any webpage on my website they will always redirected to `http://domain.com/answer.php/?ask=( THE FULL PATH URL WHERE THEY CAME FROM )`.

Can someone help me please? :)

---

FLOW UPDATE as Kumar requested. Thanks for the help buddy.

Detailed Version

I have a website `http://domain.com/`. The website has lot of pages `http://domain.com/page1/` --- `http://domain.com/(and son on)` LOT! Each of the page has a anchor text "ASK" which is link to `http://domain.com/redirect.php`and `redirect.php`will redirect to `http://domain.com/answer.php`.

What I want is the `http://domain.com/answer.php` will carry the full path url of the previous page where the user came from. and show the url like this `http://domain.com/answer.php/?ask=(THE FULL PATH WHERE THE USER CAME FROM)` .

Example: The user is from `http://domain.com/page100/` and he click the link `ask` which is redirected to `answer.php` now, he is now on `answer.php` page and he will see the full url above is `http://domain.com/answer.php/?ask=http://domain.com/page100/`

I think I have explained very well..

Thank you Kumar. Hope you can solve this!

Comment: You have to make changes in .htaccess file, go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in redirect.php add this logic

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]=="http://domain.com/ask-now/"){
    $location="http://domain.com/answer.php/?ask=".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    header("Location: $location");
}
```

You can change your logic according to your requirement.

Comment: Hello Kumar Thanks for the response but can you please write the whole redirect.php ? i do not know where to add the code you provided.... I have a very basic redirect script i got from searching... Also I was wondering if the code you provided is working also on other pages on my wordpress site. I am skeptic on this one `if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]=="http://domain.com/ask-now/"){
` I think works only on `http://domain.com/ask-now page`

Comment: I updated it. Please check above. Thanks Kumar hope you can solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply save the current users' page to COOKIE or his SESSION, and get it later. I suggest this way because HTTP_REFERER is not always transmitted.

For example:

1. User visits http://domain.com/ask-now/, php-script sets cookie, which saves currrent page url. After that it goes redirect
       to the answer.php:

> setcookie('ask_page', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], time() + 3600, /'); 
>   header("Location: /answer.php");

1. At the answer.php you will get the previous page from cookie:

> echo $_COOKIE['ask_page'];

Comment: Hello Dmitry, can you please elaborate more how this work? together with the code please? i'm really new to this stuff.

Comment: thanks very much dmitrtry, however i still don't get it. where to put that setcookie stuff? Thanks every one... perhaps i really need to hire someone on this kind of stuff... thanks for the effort. I appreciate it.