# How to rewrite profile URL without .htaccess, in PHP?

Tags: php, url-routing

I am building a router in PHP. I was wondering how I can map /profile?id=3 to /user/3. Is there any way to do this in PHP without .htaccess?

Comment: You need htaccess to rewrite the url. you cannot do it otherway.

Comment: Yes put the rewrite rules in the vhost config instead

Comment: Your sure of it? I am using the MVC pattern and redirecting all requests to index.php and requiring the router with all query strings after it. I want to make this as easy as possible for a user to rewrite the URL. @machineaddict

Comment: @PeeHaa in the vhost? Could you give an example?

Comment: @PeeHaa: the OP was made probably because the user doesn't have access to create a htacess file

Comment: @user3660432: and how are you doing that?

Comment: I didn't, but I was just wondering so it could be simpiler in the future. @PeeHaa

Comment: It works in the same way. Only difference is that you do the config where it belonsg (in the server config) instead .htaccess files changes can be disabled on certain hosts.

Comment: Dear OP, this has nothing to do with MVC. Tag has been removed. Also, it is possible to do `i.php/something/something`. In the `i.php` file the `'/something/something'` part will end up in one of `$_SERVER` params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is create a base entry point which catch all urls like in [Symfony](http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/book/routing.html), for example.

This entry point could be a `app.php` file at the root of your project. You can access it via urls like `http://yourdomain.com/app.php/user/3`.

This entry point will use the URL part after `app.php` to invoque corresponding controller, extract the user ID and render HTML.

Then, in your apache config, you create a rewrite rule that will prepend all URLs with `app.php`. `http://yourdomain.com/user/3` will be mapped under the hood by apache to `http://yourdomain.com/app.php/user/3`.

An exemple of such a rewrite rule can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php).

After that, if you want to support other routes, like `/myblog/great-entry` or anything else, you can handle them from PHP side. You won't have to edit your apache config ever again, because every URL are catched by your `app.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

The URL needs to be rewritten from that shortened form, to a query string to be passed to PHP. You cannot accept /user/3 in PHP in any way as it's not going to be populated in the $_GET superglobal array.

You don't need to put rewrite rules in .htaccess files, as they're per-directory inherited. But you still need mod_rewrite.

As you're using PHP, I'm assuming you're not running it on the CLI, so you must be using Apache or Nginx. That being the case, what's the problem running mod_rewrite and putting the rules in the config?

Comment: There is no problem, I just want it simple to rewrite a URL for the future, instead of having to come up with a rewrite rule.

Comment: What you could do is create a base entry point which catch all urls like in [Symfony](http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/book/routing.html), for example. You'll only have to put one rule in your apache config ;)

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. I would create an instance of the router, and want to pass through the page with the placeholder, and the say ID. Then I would show the page? @EliotBerriot

Comment: @user3660432, please see my anwser for details (comments are too short for this)