# How to set up a website's URL properly

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, symfony

I'm having trouble to decide how I should do to make my websites urls cleaner. The thing is, it's done with Angular AND Symfony2. Angular providing the front, and Symfony2 providing the api.

Here's my website's structure :

```
/api
    /app => configurations go here
    /bin => binaries
    /src => your bundles/MVC code
    /vendor => Symfony and 3rd party bundles
    /web => this is where the web server document root should be pointed to

/front
    /api -> Symlink to /api/web in the symfony part, working, but with app.php and app_dev.php
    /css -> frontend CSS
    /img -> frontend Images
    /js  -> frontend JS for AngularJS
    /lib
    /partials -> html templates used by AngularJS
    index.html
```

Now the urls I get are www.project.dev/ which is home, rendered by AngularJS (/front), works perfectly, and www.project.dev/api/app(_dev).php/... rendered in Symfony2 but I want to remove the part :

```
app(_dev).php
```

I have two empty .htaccess, in / and in /api, do I need to use them ? Or do I have to use the Angular-route system ?
How am I suppose to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how exactly you have your Symfony application setup, but I would recommend using the default Symfony directory structure, as it will simplify troubleshooting problems.  The default directory structure is something like this:

```
/Symfony
    /app => configurations go here
    /bin => binaries
    /src => your bundles/MVC code
    /vendor => Symfony and 3rd party bundles
    /web => this is where the web server document root should be pointed to
```

Since your document root is pointed to `/web`, you can have directories in there for your public assets, such as your `/js`, `/img`, and `/css` (Or you can look into [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html), it allows lots of cool things like combining and compressing js or css.).  The `/web` directory also has a .htaccess file included so that the `app(_dev).php` is removed from the URL.

Your `/api` can then be built using the standard Symfony routing, controllers, and views.  You should read the [Symfony routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) documentation to get a grasp of how that works.  A summary of how this works is:

1. create the route (ex. `/api/users`)
2. point the route to a Controller action (see the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#mapping-a-url-to-a-controller))
3. in the controller action, return the desired [response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-response-object)

That's how I would recommend you structure your application.  But if you would rather stick with the structure that you have, you will need to add a .htaccess file to the `/api` directory (which I assume points to the `/web` directory of the Symfony application), and take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php) for what the .htaccess file could contain.

Comment: I edited my question so you could understand better =)

Comment: did you look at the last link that I referred to? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php) shows what you can put in the .htaccess file in the web directory

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before posting and I was wondering that maybe it didn't work because of my specific structure.

Comment: It's possible.  I have never tried using a symfony application where the `/web` directory is not at the document root of the site.  Is there a specific reason that you don't want to use Symfony for the whole application?

Comment: Well, I think using AngularJS as a templating system, over a Symfony RESTFul API seems a very good idea. I want to see it through, as the results I'm getting now are really promising.

Comment: I agree, it is a great idea.  It can be done using Symfony for serving the AngularJS templates/views as well.  But let us know how it goes with your setup.