# Subpages not work on prod enviroment. Something wrong with routing?

Tags: php, symfony

I have problem to connect to some webs on prod.
When I try visit addres on local
`http://localhost:1337/zespol_noico/web/app_dev.php/formularz/kontakt`
it works,

`http://localhost:1337/zespol_noico/web/formularz/kontakt`
works.

On server:
`http://dreamwebstudio.pl/works/zespol/web/app_dev.php/formularz/kontakt`
works
but prod website
`http://dreamwebstudio.pl/works/zespol/web/formularz/intro`
not works. `404 Not Found.  The request /works/zespol/web/formularz/intro was not found on this server.`
I have no idea why. I cleared prod cache if someone ask. I'd like to mentioned that mainpage `http://dreamwebstudio.pl/works/zespol/web/` works fine.
In default controller my annotation:

```
/**
 * @Route("/formularz/muzyka", name="formularz_muzyka")
 * @Template()
 */
public function muzykaAction(Request $Request){
    $Repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyFrontendBundle:Muzyka');
    $Register = $Repo->find("1");

    $form = $this->createForm(new MuzykaEditType(), $Register);
    $form->handleRequest($Request);
    $Muzyka = new MuzykaEditType();

    if ($Request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($Register);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe the server does not have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: In `.htaccess `is `RewriteEngine on`. I noticed that `http://dreamwebstudio.pl/works/zespol/web/app.php/formularz/intro` works too so the problem is with `app.php/app_dev.php` in address

Comment: It might be something else completly. But having `RewriteEngine on` in your .htaccess does not meen it's on. Make sure the module is loaded by your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution on [symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11149570/4418289)
Problem for me was that I put code to .htaccess on main directory instead of in ../web/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```