# Symfony 2 - .htaccess bundle paths are broken

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I've found [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665911/1208233), which must fix the rewrite ability for assets. However, it doesn't work for Symfony 2.4. And by doesn't work, I mean that assets aren't being rewritten and bundle paths are still broken.

I've tried playing with rewrite rules manually with no luck so far. I simply can't get why this correct rule

```
# Fix the bundles folder
RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]
```

doesn't internally redirect all requests to `/web/bundles`? Anything else, including routes work correctly. So what causes this rewrite rule to fail?

Comment: Is your vhost configuration pointing to the ``web`` or parent of ``web`` directory?

Comment: @eRIZ Can't access vhost since I'm using shared hosting. That must be done in `.htaccess` And that `.htaccess` located in the parent directory of `web` (i.e root)

Comment: Okay, so what's the result of pointing a browser at ``/web/bundles/testbundle/(...)``? httpd error or Symfony route error?

Comment: @eRIZ When pointing, for example, to `/web/bundles/framework/css/structure.css` it works displaying content of `structure.css`. What I'm trying to rewrite, is when pointing to `/bundles/framework/css/structure.css` it would fetch contents from `/web/bundles/framework/css/structure.css`, so I find it quite strange that `RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]` doesn't work as expected

Comment: Try dumping your assets using assetic dump command. This will help you out.

Comment: But you've not specified what error you see.

Comment: 404 from Symfony or httpd?