# How to create route for example.com/username in Symfony and preserve all old URLs

Tags: php, symfony, routes

**Goal:**

I want Username URLs like Facebook, Twitter etc.: `example.com/Username`

**Problem**:

URLs like `/register` etc. can not then be reached if I add

```
   * @Route("/{user}", name="user_profile")
```

Of course I could have `/user/username`, but I need for this case `/username`.

What is the correct way of implementing this?

One idea was adding an event listener for 404 pages which checks if the URL is `example.com/abc` and check if the username exists. But that seems like a bad hack.

**Short question:**

How is it possible to make a route `www.example.com/username` like Facebook, without conflicts with `/registe`r etc. in a professional way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php you should rewrite the url then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to define how you want to deal with collisions of paths like `/register`, `/login`, `/impressum` and usernames colliding with these paths (like "register", "login" and "impressum"). You probably want to have a blacklist of usernames which are not allowed, because they collide with your pre-defined paths.

To solve the actual problem then, you can create a "catchall" route for `/{username}` (maybe with some restrictions on the `{username}` part using regex) **after** all the other routes.

When you request a path in a symfony project, symfony will check the routes in the order they were defined. So if you define your user profile route last (at the bottom of the routing.yml file), it will only be used if all other routes did not match the request.
This means, if you have a user with a name like "register", he would not be able to open his profile page, since the `/register` route for the registration page would match the request first.

In Symfony Standard Edition routing is like this:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

You can't handle route position with annotations, except if you write multiple entries in the `routing.yml` file. To make sure the user profile route is last, you should probably remove the annotation for this action and create the route by using yml, like this:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

user_profile:
    path: /{user}
    defaults:
        _controller: App:User:profile
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias, that is exactly what I was looking for! One note though, it only worked in dev env, on prod it gave me a 404. After clearing the cache via ./bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod; ./bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod it doesn't worked as well. I had to manually clear the cache via rm -rf app/cache/*, then it worked. I'll accept your answer now, again thank you!